# Convert RDD[Array[(String,String)]] type to RDD[(String,String)] in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Scala and tried multiple things to convert `RDD[Array[(String,String)]]` type to `RDD[(String,String)]`.

What I want to achive is to select from a Json two elements (text and category). For every word in the text, I just want to create a key/value pair in the form (word1, category), (word2, category), ....

My example looks like this:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
// Example Json-line: {"reviewText": "This was a gift!", "category": "Apps"}"
val rdd = sc.textFile(PathToJSONFile)
rdd.map{    
   row =>
   val json_row = parse(row)
   val myCategory = compact(json_row \ "category").toString
   val myText = compact(json_row \ "reviewText").toString.toLowerCase.split("[#&$!]").map(_.trim).filter(_.length > 1)
   myText.map{word => (word, myCategory)}
}
```

The output is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[(String, String)]]` and looks like this:

```
Array(Array((this,"Apps"), (was,"Apps"), (a,"Apps"), (gift,"Apps"))
```

But what I want to achieve is a key value pair in the form of `RDD[(String,String)]` (where key is a word and the value is the same category for every word in this line)

How can I achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: change `rdd.map` to `rdd.flatMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions from Psidom solved the problem.
Changing `rdd.map to rdd.flatMap` was the solution.